# how to make pdf document responsive

Tags: html, css

I am using `embed` tag to return a pdf document. How can i make the pdf document responsive to screen without using `height` and `width` properties for `embed` tag?

This is what i tried so far but it doesnt display the pdf correctly. Please check the code on codepen link below:

https://codepen.io/Nick1212/pen/LePKWw

`HTML`:

```
<div>
  <embed src='https://gradcollege.okstate.edu/sites/default/files/PDF_linking' />  
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
.pdf-embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I'd also like to know if `iframe` tag is a better solution for this.

UPDATE: Please check the codepen link. But pdf doesnt change on changing screen size. I could make the pdf bigger but Pdf stays same size.

```
.responsive {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.2%;
  height: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks. The link is about making `video` responsive. will that work for pdf?

Comment: If used correctly, it should work with any iframe or embed.

Comment: yeah i just tried to change screen size but pdf stays the same :(

Comment: Usually, PDFs have a certain page/paper size set. I don't think it's possible to change that "from outside" to make them responsive the way a website is responsive.

Comment: Given the question tags (and [tag:pdf] not even showing up) I suspect you're actually asking about the rendered view generated by whatever incarnation of [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) your current browser bundles. You should really edit the question and assert all this explicitly. The PDF format itself was carefully designed to not be responsive at all.